# Use the share button on a picture from mobile gallery to upload it on PWA

Tags: javascript, reactjs, progressive-web-apps, next.js

Is it possible to share a picture directly from mobile gallery to a PWA (same behaviour as What's app or Messenger when we want to send a picture) or do I need a native app to do that? The website I'm building allow a user to upload a media (with an input type file), but the user would have to access the website first to share it. I also want to allow him to select its media first, then share it to the app, and I wonder if this behavior is doable with a PWA.

Comment: Check my new updated answer,

Answer (score 5):

// Updated

You can register as a share target by with the web share target API, Twitter PWA uses this and here is a section from their manifest that handles that

```
  "share_target": {
    "action": "compose/tweet",
    "enctype": "multipart/form-data",
    "method": "POST",
    "params": {
      "title": "title",
      "text": "text",
      "url": "url",
      "files": [
        {
          "name": "externalMedia",
          "accept": [
            "image/jpeg",
            "image/png",
            "image/gif",
            "video/quicktime",
            "video/mp4"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
```

You can read more about it [Here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/12/web-share-target)

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see the feature I mentioned above in the Chromes Features link.

Comment: @Blq56 Further research and noticed you can register as a share target, [Read more](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/12/web-share-target)

Comment: Thanks @none to try helping me. I already found Web Share Target API and this is not exactly what I'm looking for. On a mobile phone, in the gallery, when you click on a picture, there is a share button. When you click on "share", you can share the picture through different app (Discord, Messenger, E-mail...). Is it possible to display, beside these apps, my own PWA in order to share the picture through my PWA or I need to build a native app? (Or maybe I don't understand what Web Share Target API is able to do.

Comment: That is exactly what it is able to do, Go through the article

Comment: Here is a picture of what happens when I hit the share of an image in my gallery. https://ibb.co/WWM3kZm.  FYI : the Twitter In the image is a PWA. I don't have the native Twitter. So that answers your question. Once you've registered your app(pwa) as a share target it's added to the share options. Of the specific media types you accept